# // コメントの後ろのスペースの有無について言及したコーディング規約はありますか？

Tags: php

PHP のコメントで//を使う場合、//の後ろにはスペース入れるものですか？入れないものですか？　主要なコーディング規約で言及されているものがあれば知りたいです。

```
// コメント
```

or

```
//コメント
```

PSR のページ見るとサンプルは前者で書かれていますが、特に言及されている箇所は見つけられなかったです。
当たり前すぎるのか、特にルールはないのか。(言及されているけれど見つけられてないだけか)
記事サイトなどは前者が多いですが、後者で書いている人もたまに見かけます。

言及されている規約がある場合は教えていただけますとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [Manual:Coding conventions/PHP](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Coding_conventions/PHP) を見ますと、`In comments there should be one space between the # or // character and the comment.` と書かれていますね。

Comment: おお。metropolisさん
ありがとうございます。

Comment: タグに [php] とありますが、PHP に限定したご質問でしょうか？

Comment: nekketsuuuさん
PHPがわかれば今は充分なのですが、
できれば主要なコーディング規約が知りたいです。

タグは規約等のが見つけられなかったので仮でつけさせていただきました。

Comment: @r-naga さん、コメントを受けて内容を書き直してみました。異なる部分があれば上書きして頂ければと思います。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こちらのご質問がオフトピックなのかどうかについて、「メタ」という、サイトの使い方について聞くサイトに投稿しました: https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2714/19110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPではありませんが、PythonのスタイルガイドPEP 8では、`#`とスペース1つで始めるべき、とあります。

- [はじめに — pep8-ja 1.0 ドキュメント](http://pep8-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/#id19)
- [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code | Python.org](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments)

言語仕様としては、コメント開始トークンの後のスペースはoptionalであり、requiredではありませんが、コメントの可読性を向上させるため、また「コードの一時的なコメントアウト」ではなく「説明としてのコメント」であることを明らかにするためにも、スペースを入れるように規定しているのだと思われます。

Answer (score 1):

私が調べた限りだと、PHP の行コメント `//` の後にスペースを入れるかについて明示的に書かれた有名なコーディング規約はありませんでした。

PHP の標準的なコーディング規約には [PHP Standard Recommendation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_Standard_Recommendation) (PSR) に含まれる [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/), [PSR-2](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) および [PSR-12](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/extended-coding-style-guide.md) がありますが、これらはコメントの仕方には言及していません。PSR を作っている団体のメーリングリストも覗いて見ましたが、[ドキュメント用コメントについての議論](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/php-fig/o4ko1XsGtAw)以外は見当たりませんでした。

その他だと、PHP で書かれたソフトウェアで採用されているコーディング規約があります。Qiita の記事[「PHPコーディング規約まとめ」](https://qiita.com/hshimo/items/04be1f432240c58300f4)が "いいね" をたくさんもらっていたので、これに載っているコーディング規約たちがコメントに言及しているか調べてみましたが、`//` の後のスペースについて明示的に書いているものは**ありませんでした**。

以下の規約たちにはドキュメント用以外のコメントについて書かれていませんでした。

- [Zend Framework Coding Standard for PHP (1.x)](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/ja/coding-standard.coding-style.html)
- [Zend Framework Coding Standard for PHP (2.x)](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/ref/coding.standard.html)
- [Symfony Coding Standards](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html) (古い日本語版は[こちら](http://docs.symfony.gr.jp/symfony2/contributing/code/standards.html))
- [Yii Core framework code style (1.x)](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/wiki/Core-framework-code-style)

以下の規約たちには、通常のコメントについて言及があるものの、`//` の後のスペースについて明示的には書かれていませんでした。

- [PEAR Coding Standards](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/coding-standards.php) : コメントについての記述は[こちら](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.comments.php)
- [CakePHP Coding Conventions (2.x)](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html)
- [CakePHP Coding Conventions (3.x)](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/ja/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html)
- [CodeIgniter PHP Style Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html)
- [Yii 2 Core Framework Code Style](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/internals/core-code-style.md)
- [Laravel Coding Style](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/contributions#coding-style) および StyleCI の [Laravel プリセット](https://styleci.readme.io/docs/presets#section-laravel)
- [WordPress PHP Coding Standards](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/wordpress-coding-standards/php/) および [WordPress PHP Documentation Standards](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/inline-documentation-standards/php/)

最後に "PHP coding standards" で検索すると上位に出てくる中に含まれる [FuelPHP Coding Standards](https://fuelphp.com/docs/general/coding_standards.html) も見てみましたが、こちらもドキュメント以外のコメントについては言及がありませんでした。

個人的には、コードの意味を説明する意図の行コメントには `//` の後にスペースを入れる方式がよく使われているように思います。しかし、コーディング規約で明確に示しているものは見つかりませんでした。